# XPath validation returns false

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, x509

EDIT.
I have a problem with XmlDsigXPathTransform valiation. Sad to say even when I copied 1:1 the example from docs the xpath validations ends failed. What am I missing? I can't figure anything anymore about this when even the docs example fails.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.xmldsigxpathtransform?view=netframework-4.6.1

```
var signatureReference = new Reference { Uri = "", };
XmlDsigXPathTransform XPathTransform = 
CreateXPathTransform(XPathString);
signatureReference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
signatureReference.AddTransform(XPathTransform);
signedXml.AddReference(signatureReference);

 private static XmlDsigXPathTransform CreateXPathTransform(string XPathString)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement xPathElem = doc.CreateElement("XPath");
        xPathElem.InnerText = XPathString;
        XmlDsigXPathTransform xForm = new XmlDsigXPathTransform();
        xForm.LoadInnerXml(xPathElem.SelectNodes("."));
        return xForm;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `XmlDsigXPathTransform` is no longer considered safe, so any document using it is automatically considered to have an invalid signature.

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Security/system/security/cryptography/xml/signedxml.cs,8b616077b30145cd

If you really want to use it, you have to enable it in the Windows Registry on whatever computers are going to call CheckSignature.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/after-you-apply-security-update-3141780-net-framework-applications-encounter-exception-errors-or-unexpected-failures-while-processing-files-that-contain-signedxml-922edd45-a91e-c755-bb30-2604acf37362

SignedXml is old and outdated, my recommendation is to not use it at all, unless you have to for compatibility (the .NET team calls it legacy and says it's not being invested in on issues, e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44674#issuecomment-875163316).

Comment: I was only following the bad documentation for the NEW Api we need to integrate before next year. In the time it's discovered that I don't need to use it, im using only enveloped signature and c14n and the signature is somehow validated( because I use my own SSL cert it can't validate it fully). Yet I need to use the :ds prefix... well a great feature but not for me in Net 4.6.1 where every code sample breaks the signature. Is there any free library that covers SignedXML?